# Passing lists from one function to another in Swift

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

I can't quite understand why I can't past an Int[] from one function to another:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}

func average(numbers:Int...) -> Double {
    var sum = sumOf(numbers)

    return Double(sum) / Double(numbers.count)
}
```

This gives me the following error:

`Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:138:19: error: could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments`

```
var sum = sumOf(numbers)
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `numbers: Int...` parameter in `sumOf` is called a *variadic parameter*. That means you can pass in a variable number of that type of parameter, and everything you pass in is converted to an array of that type for you to use within the function.

Because of that, the `numbers` parameter inside `average` is an array, not a group of parameters like `sumOf` is expecting.

You might want to overload `sumOf` to accept either one, like this, so your averaging function can call the appropriate version:

```
func sumOf(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    return sumOf(numbers)
}
```

Comment: They should add this to the language. For example c# allows you to simply pass the array as well.

Comment: The new syntax requires [Int] instead of Int[]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by replacing `Int...` with `Int[]` in `sumOf()`.

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int[]) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}

func average(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    var sum = sumOf(numbers)

    return Double(sum) / Double(numbers.count)
}

average(3,4,5)
```

Your problem is `Int...` is a variable amount of Ints while `Int[]` is an array of `Int`. When sumOf is called it turns the parameters into an Array called numbers. You then try to pass that Array to sumOf, but you had written it to take a variable number of Ints instead of an Array of Ints.

Comment: Only issue with this approach is that `sumOf(3, 4, 5)` will no longer work, so you'd have to do the overload approach as suggested by Nate Cook above. (It seems to me that conversion should be implicit, but perhaps that violates the "no implicit conversions" philosophy Swift has adopted.)