# Function taking a variable number of arguments

Tags: swift

In this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1

It mentions that when creating `for` loops we can use the shorthand of `0..3` and `0...3` to replace `i = 0; i < 3; ++i` and `i = 0; i <= 3; ++i` respectively.

All very nice.

Further down the document in the Functions and Closures section it says that functions can have a variable number of arguments passed via an array.

However, in the code example we see the `...` again.

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
var sum = 0
for number in numbers {
sum += number
}
return sum
}
```

Is this a mistake?  It seems to me that a more intuitive syntax would be `numbers: Int[]`.

A few examples down we see another code sample which has exactly that:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: Int[], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
```

Comment: Don't you distinguish between passing an array and passing varargs? It's 2 different use cases.

Comment: Not according to the docs which say: _Functions can also take a variable number of arguments, collecting them into an array._ right before the example using `...`

Comment: The "_collecting them into an array_" part means those variable arguments are accessible as an array, not `va_list`.

Comment: Oh I see!  Thanks all.  Not sure why this question got marked down.  I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 53):

In case of all arguments are Int numbers: Int[] would be intuitive. But if you have code like this:

```
func foo(args:AnyObject...) {
    for arg: AnyObject in args {
        println(arg)
    }
}

foo(5, "bar", NSView())
```

output:

```
5
bar
<NSView: 0x7fc5c1f0b450>
```

Comment: You can find out more about Variadic Parameters (...) in the docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Answer (score 5):

The type of parameter in sumOf are known as 'variadic' parameter.
The parameters passed are accepted just as a group of elements and is then converted into array before using it within that function.

A great example would be this post.

[Passing lists from one function to another in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008547/passing-lists-from-one-function-to-another-in-swift?rq=1)