# get amount of NSCalendarUnits in NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents

i want to write a function, which returns specific NSCalendarUnits from a String.
My function therefore takes as many NSCalendarUnits as arguments as the user wants to.

```
public extension String{
    func calendarComponents(units: NSCalendarUnit, separateString: String) -> NSDateComponents{
    // now i want to know which units the user specified 
    // so i can scan the string for integerValues and add them to 
    // the corresponding component
    }
}
```

as a result i want the user to define a String like var myStringDate = "4/5" and then use the function

```
 myStringDate.calendarComponents(units: .CalendarUnitMonth |    
 .CalendarUnitWeekday, "/")
```

and then get a NSDateComponent object with .month = 4 and .weekday = 5.

i do know how to scan the string for all the needed Values, but i don't know, how to add those values to the right component attribute.

Comment: You can't do it like this, because units are used as a flag. So you can't retrieve them in "order". But you can look for *Variable Arguments Lists*, example question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035832/function-taking-a-variable-number-of-arguments
And use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to strip the `NSString`.

Comment: i am not quite sure how u think I should do it, but i came up with a solution (your answer helped me a lot though, see the big answer)

Comment: I just pointed potential hints. I pointed the fact that .CalendarUnitMont|.CalendarUnitWeekDay returns .CalendarUnitMont+.CalendarUnitWeekDay, so it's hard to retrieve the "order" after (1+2 or 2+1 results the same as a simpler example). The rest is up to you. But I'd suggest that you post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is this:

first create an NSDateComponents extension:

```
extension NSDateComponents{
func calendarUnit(unit: NSCalendarUnit, value: Int) -> Bool{
    switch unit{
    case NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitEra:
        self.era = value
        return true
    case NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear:
        self.year = value
        return true
    // ....
    case NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitNanosecond:
        self.nanosecond = value
        return true
    default:
        return false
        }
    }
}
```

and then simply create an String extension like this:

```
public extension String{

func dateComponents(separatorString: String ,units: NSCalendarUnit...) -> NSDateComponents {
    var stringComponents = self.componentsSeparatedByString(separatorString)
    var components = NSDateComponents()
    var counter = 0


    for unit in units{
        var value = components.calendarUnit(unit, value: stringComponents[counter].toInt()!)
        counter++
    }

    return components

   }
}
```