# How to convert [Int] to Int... in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion

I am executing the tasks in GuideTour Playground for Swift.
And there is a function for sum:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var sum = 0
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return sum
}
```

And after that there a task:
**Write a function that calculates the average of its arguments.**

I want to write smth like:

```
func avg(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    return Double(sumOf(numbers)) / Double(numbers.count)
}
```

But XCode shows the warning: **'[Int]' is not convertible to 'Int'**

Does anybody know how to make this convertion?

**PS:** I know that I can get the solution with Array-parameter. I am interested in the solution with 'Int...' only. It is just the academic interest.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Passing lists from one function to another in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008547/passing-lists-from-one-function-to-another-in-swift).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a function to get the sum of your array of Int, use `reduce`

```
func avg(numbers: [Int]) -> Double {
    return numbers.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 } / Double(numbers.count)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for functional approach to this task, but I ask anly about convertion '[Int]' to 'Int...'. Anyway, you also offer very beautiful solution.