# why swift function with variadic parameters can not receive an array as argument

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

as the title, why swift variadic parameters cannot receive an array as the argument? 
for instance:

```
func test(ids : Int...){
    //do something
}
//call function test like this failed
test([1,3])
//it can only receive argument like this
test(1,3)
```

Sometimes, I can only get array data, and I also need the function can receive variadic parameters, but not an array parameter. Maybe I shoud define two function, one receive array parameter, and another receive variadic parameter, is there any other solution except this one?

Comment: Compare [Passing lists from one function to another in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008547/passing-lists-from-one-function-to-another-in-swift).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload the function definition...

```
func test(ids : Int...) {
    print("\(ids.count) rx as variadic")
}
func test(idArr : [Int]) {
    print("\(idArr.count) rx as array")
}
//call function test like this now succeeds
test([1,3])
//... as does this
test(1,3)

// Output:
// "2 rx as array"    
// "2 rx as variadic"
```

Of course, to avoid duplicate code, the variadic version should just call the array version:

```
func test(ids : Int...) {
    print("\(ids.count) rx as variadic")
    test(ids, directCall: false)
}
func test(idArr : [Int], directCall: Bool = true) {
    // Optional directCall allows us to know who called...
    if directCall {
        print("\(idArr.count) rx as array")
    }
    print("Do something useful...")
}

//call function test like this now succeeds
test([1,3])
//... as does this
test(1,3)

// Output:
// 2 rx as array
// Do something useful...
// 2 rx as variadic
// Do something useful...
```

Comment: Finally, I add a overload for this method like this
func test(ids : Int...) {
    test(ids)
}
It seems I must define two method to do this. Thank you very much.
func test(idArr : [Int]) {
    print("\(idArr.count) rx as array")
}

Comment: Yes, to avoid duplicated code, you need to call the Array version from the variadic one. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> A variadic parameter accepts zero or more values of a specified type.

If you want/need to have any object type (Array, whatever) in that variadic parameter, use this:

```
func test(ids: AnyObject...) {
    // Do something 
}
```